# VBA - loop to standardize header in some worksheets but omit some

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through 11 of the 13 worksheets I have in my workbook to standardize some column headers. When running the macro, it is only making the changes on the currently active worksheet.

I've tried putting an if statement with the names of the sheets to omit. This is what I have

```
Sub Set_Headings()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'loop through each sheet in the workbook except for "Main" and "Overall" and standardize column headers'
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Main" And ws.Name <> "Overall" Then
            Range("B2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
            Range("E2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
            Range("H2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
            Range("K2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
            Range("C2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
            Range("F2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
            Range("I2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
            Range("L2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
            Range("G2").Value = "Drivers"
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I expect for those headers to be applied in all the sheets except "Main" and "Overall" but it is only applying the changes to the currently active worksheet.

Comment: put `ws.` in front of all the `Range(...`: `ws.Range(...`

Comment: Ah... simple fix. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, after the `For each ws ...` line, add `With ws`, then you can do `If .Name <> ...` and `.Range("B2").Value = ...` (note just the `.`, don't need `ws.` since you have it in `With ws` ...if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you don't explicitly state which worksheet you would like to use with your `Range` then it will default to the current `ActiveSheet`.

An example using one of your lines would be `ws.Range("L2").Value = "Unit / Notes"`.

As @BruceWayne stated, using a [`With`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) statement will make your code more readable by eliminating repetitive qualifying expressions.

```vb
Sub Set_Headings()
    'loop through each sheet in the workbook except for "Main" and "Overall" and standardize column headers'
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Name <> "Main" And .Name <> "Overall" Then
                .Range("B2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
                .Range("E2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
                .Range("H2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
                .Range("K2").Value = "Active / Days Off / Holidays/ Training / MOD / LOA"
                .Range("C2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
                .Range("F2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
                .Range("I2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
                .Range("L2").Value = "Unit / Notes"
                .Range("G2").Value = "Drivers"
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't call it "not explicit", it is **implicit** what happens a lot without users care about (or even notice).  Maybe add [avoiding implicit code](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/clean-vba-code-pt-2-avoiding-implicit-code/)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher could you elaborate? Your comment wasn't very explicit in what you were trying to communicate ;) I feel like it can be written in either way, either share the implicit default reference, or share that the developer must be explicit in which reference to use.

Comment: The usage of implicisms like`ActiveSheet`, if no sheet supplied or omitting the default-member like`.Value()` or implicit conversion of data-types, is widespread, but especially beginners, don't notice what they do, because most time it has the expected behavior. So start with sth like "If you don't specify the worksheet to a range, `AcriveSheet.Range`is implicit used as worksheet the range belongs to'  And add the link from my comments as it offers some deeper thougths on implicisms.